# Best Type for UTF-8 data?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

What is the best type, in C++, for storing UTF-8 string? I'd like to avoid rolling my own class if possible.

My original thought was `std::string` — however, this uses `char` as the underlying type. `char` may be unsigned or signed — it varies. On my system, it's signed. UTF-8 code units, however, are *unsigned* octets. This seems to indicate that it's the wrong type.

This leads us to `std::basic_string<unsigned char>` - which seems to fit the bill: unsigned, 8-bit (or larger) chars.

However, most things seem to use `char`. glib, for example, uses `char`. C++'s `ostream`'s use `char`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd just use std::string, as it is consistent with the UTF-8 ideal of treating data just as you would null-terminated ASCII strings unless you actually need their unicode-ness.

I also like GTKmm's Glib::ustring, but that only works if you're writing a GTKmm (or at least Glibmm) application.

Comment: The only real problem with using std::string is that some operators which are expected to work on characters could actually end up dealing with partial characters since UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding. For example, using operator[] would be broken for getting "characters" in addition to the string length not being directly accessible. (Size is available, but not length).

Comment: You just need to think of a string being an array of code units instead of an array of characters.  Then the only `string` member functions that don't work are those like `find_one_of` that take a set of characters as an argument.

Comment: @Evan: The definition of "characters" and "length" are so complex in Unicode (because of combining and ligatures and stuff), that they won't ever be directly accessible. It's kind of better not to pretend they are.

Answer (score 7):

I've always just used std::string, myself -- somehow, the "signed" vs "unsigned" philosophical question just about never comes up as problematic in such a context (encoders and decoders to/from UTF-8 are things you only write rarely, after all; in an application context, you're just using the std::string as a "black box" of sorts!-).

Answer (score 4):

UTF-8 is a *variable-length* character encoding. `std::basic_string` supports only *fixed-length* character encodings. If you need to support *variable-length* encodings you could try [ICU4C library](http://site.icu-project.org/).

> ICU is a mature, widely used set of C/C++ and Java libraries providing Unicode and Globalization support for software applications. ICU is widely portable and gives applications the same results on all platforms and between C/C++ and Java software.

If you need just *to store* UTF-8 string I'd recommend to use `std::vector<char>`. That will indicate that you cannot perform actual string operations (which could be incorrect) on stored data.